# Setting cookie on click fancybox close button

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I know about jquery cookie plugin .But I am stuck to set cookie on click close button.
Here is my approach.

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-latest.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src="jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fancybox.css">
 <script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

then for cookie and fancybox

```
$(".fancybox-close").on("click", function () {
    $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });
});
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery.fancybox(jQuery(".popup"), {
        // other API options
    }); 
});
```

The html code

```
  <div class="popup" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Hi there </h1>
  </div>
```

I see that if I do

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });
```

this set cookie but I want to set on click close button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
jQuery(function() {
    $.fancybox($(".popup"), {
        // other API options
    });

    // put your code inside dom ready callback too.
    // and delegate the click event on document
    $(document).on('click', '.fancybox-close', function () {
        $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });
    });
});
```